# Throughput measure

Tags: traffic-measurement

I have to implement a limitation algorithm in order to avoid to reach a throughput limit imposed by the service I'm interacting with.

The limit is specified as «N requests over 1 day» where N is of the order of magnitude of 10^6.

I have a distributed system of clients interacting with the service so they should share the measure.

An exact solution should involve to record all the events and than computing the limit «when» the event of calling the service occur: of course this approach is too expensive and so I'm looking for an approximate solution.

The first one I devised imply to discretize the detection of the events: for example maintaing 24 counters at most and recording the number of requests occurred within an hour.

Acceptable.

But I feel that a more elegant, even if leaded by different «forces», is to declinate the approach to the continuum.

Let's say recording the last N events I could easily infer the «current» throughput. Of course this algorithm suffer for missing consideration of the past events occurred the hours before. I could improve with with an aging algorithm but… and here follow my question:

Q: «There's an elegant approximate solution to the problem of estimating the throughput of a service over a long period with and high rate of events?»

Comment: Are your clients going through a central point or are they all talking to the limited service directly?

Comment: Also what is the behaviour when the limit is exceeded? Do you just need to monitor or rate limit the clients?

Comment: Of course the talker is centralized within a common component used by applicative clients. When the limit is reached, simply, all calls are ignored with an OVER_QUOTA error message.

Comment: The really obvious solution is to use a counter in the central component but this doesn't seem like a solution you want to use and I'm not sure i understand why. A long can easily hold the count of requests.

Comment: The solution you provide doesn't take into account the «sliding windows».

Comment: Of course it doesn't as a raw counter. The thing to do would be to sample it every 15 minutes. If I get time I'll write something up in full and show you as an answer.

Comment: Did my answer help below?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, you should use a monitor and have it sample the values every 15 minutes or something to get a reasonable guess of the number of requests.

I mocked something up here but haven't tested it, should give you a starter.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestCounter {

private final Monitor monitor;

private TestCounter() {
    monitor = new Monitor();
}

/** The thing you are limiting */
public void myService() {
    if (monitor.isThresholdExceeded()) {
        //Return error
    } else {
        monitor.incremenetCounter();
        //do stuff
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestCounter t = new TestCounter();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        t.myService();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        t.myService();
    }
}

private class Monitor {
    private final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    private int counter = 1;

    /** Number of 15 minute periods in a day. */
    private final int numberOfSamples = 76;

    private final int threshold = 1000000;

    private boolean thresholdExceeded;

    public Monitor() {
        //Schedule a sample every 15 minutes.
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sampleCounter();
            }
        }, 0l, 900000 /** ms in 15 minutes */
        );
    }

    /** Could synchroinise */
    void incremenetCounter() {
        counter++;
    }

    /** Could synchroinise */
    void sampleCounter() {
        int tempCount = counter;
        counter = 0;
        queue.add(tempCount);

        if (queue.size() > numberOfSamples) {
            queue.poll();
        }

        int totalCount = 0;
        for (Integer value : queue) {
            totalCount += value;
        }
        if (totalCount > threshold) {
            thresholdExceeded = true;
        } else {
            thresholdExceeded = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isThresholdExceeded() {
        return thresholdExceeded;
    }
}
}
```